# Case Dashboard- Cases with upcoming activities and Cases with recently performed activities lists show empty

Tags: civicase

In the case dashboard (D7, Civi 5.8.2)

The lists of cases with recently performed or upcoming activities are showing no results
[image: snapshot of case dashboard]

Even though I know there are cases that meet the criteria.

Additionally the find cases results list is not showing any links under Most Recent or Next Scheduled

[image: case results list]

I think this is a local issue. I had a problem with the site yesterday and restored to overnight backup.

Looks like no data is lost, but these activities aren't showing

**UPDATE**
My colleague has found 2 SQL views upcoming and most recent activities. Which were not rebuilt during the back up process.

Waiting for confirmation from client all is as expected. Will post more details as an answer later.

Comment: Have you tested against a more recent version than 5.8.2? Was it always like this for this installation or did something there change recently?

Comment: Hi Demerit, I was in the middle of editting as you posted.

This is following a db backup yesterday. Functionality was lost after back up.

sandbox works as expected. other sites with case installed work as expected

Comment: So on manage case for a given case the activities show? if they don't show there, then sounds like something wrong with the civicrm_case_activity table.

Comment: Yes all activities show in individual case management views. Am "fairly" confident all the activities are there that should be.

Comment: I might check the civi logs and see if there's any warnings. Can also turn on sql debugging and see if the dashboard query might give a clue. https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/Debugging

Comment: CiviCRM debugging and backtrace enabled- no error messages

Drupal Watchdog logging enabled

Comment: Went back to case dashboard
 Message: Notice: Undefined index: all in CRM_Case_Page_AJAX::getCases() (line 201 of /home/newpip/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/AJAX.php).

Comment: Try SQL debugging, to see what it's actually trying to pull to give a clue to what's missing, not civicrm debugging.

Comment: Does it let you create a new case? If you add an activity to a case does it then show on the dashboard as recent?

Comment: Yes we can add new cases.

They appear in the summary of involvement table on the dashboard

Comment: Hi Demerit. Quick word to say thanks for your suggestions so far.

We're going to try and re-install the back up onto a fresh site to see if the issue lies with the back up process.

Comment: No prob. I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: clear caches, clear caches and once more clear caches?

Comment: Yup, we did a lot of that.

Comment: Probably a stupid suggestion, but a drupal view could give you the data you want but no idea what CMS you are on.

Comment: Hi Pete it is drupal, but it's some core case features that are not working as expected so a new view wouldn't work here. See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Case creates 2 SQL views

civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming
civicrm_view_case_activity_recent

And in case dashboard/ find case results- these views are called on to provide upcoming and recent activity data.

When the database was restored from backup. These views had been emptied. And upcoming/ most recent activity data was showing as empty on the dashboards.

A colleague found some related SQL commands in
public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php
function createCaseViewsQuery line 3057

And by running the related SQL Query was able to repopulate the views. These now automatically repopulate each time an activity is added.

Comment: This was really useful, thanks Craig, got me out of a hole. Perhaps needs to be reported as a bug? I had this exact problem after restoring a 5.28.3 system.

Comment: I added a comment to this issue https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2262

Comment: Thanks for taking up the issue Andy, I think i'd assumed it was a local issue rather than a more generic one.